# Setting object attributes in a loop results in all attributes having the same value

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to wire up some buttons to a Raspberry Pi to have different behaviour when they are pressed. I want each of them to print their name and state when the button is pressed or released. In this example I instantiate three buttons, and set their `when_pressed` and `when_released` attributes in the for-loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gpiozero import LED, Button
from signal import pause

buttons = {
    "bcn": Button(2),
    "land": Button(3),
    "taxi": Button(4)
}

for name, btn in buttons.items():
    btn.when_pressed = lambda: print(name + ' ON')
    btn.when_released = lambda: print(name + ' OFF')

print('ready')
pause()
```

But, when I press the buttons, they report the correct state, but all of them report the same name. For example, all buttons might report `bcn ON` or `bcn OFF`. Strangely, when I restart the script, another -seemingly random- name is chosen and all buttons report e.g. `land ON` or `land OFF`.

It seems to me like it is only creating a single lambda function for all press handlers, and one for all release handlers. How can I modify this script to print the correct name for each button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your lambdas to `lambda name=name: print(name + ' ON')`. In your case, a `name` is bound to the local `name` value from `for` context.